# How is the word thresholding formed?

Tags: nouns

I know the word threshold is noun.

And generally gerund is verb + ing

But how is the word thresholding formed?

Is the word from noun + ing possible?

Comment: "But how the word thresholding is formed?" is wrongly ordered. Inversion is mandatory here

Comment: Edited. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Verbing weirds language, as the saying goes.  The use of nouns as verbs occurs fairly frequently, though there may be difficulty in the meaning.  I am not be at all sure what is meant by "thresholding" out of context, and I might be even if you provided it.

I will assume, for example's sake, that it means "crossing the threshold."  Let us suppose it's in the discussion of college classes, where six students need to apply for a class to be held, and thus, six students are the threshold.

In that context, it might make sense to say

> Thresholding in math class occurs in the first three days of registration if at all, but in philosophy, generally takes a week.

Comment: Thresholding as a verb is mainly used in contexts like data processing, to mean applying a threshold (which affects how data is treated). I can't find this in dictionaries but it's in technical texts in data processing and similar fields, e.g. from [Medium](https://blog.insightdatascience.com/visualizing-machine-learning-thresholds-to-make-better-business-decisions-4ab07f823415) "Once you’ve decided to threshold, data visualization techniques like the ones in this post will let you understand the tradeoffs you face for each possible threshold choice" (The text also uses "thresholding" a lot).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mary!

Answer (score 0):

"Thresholding" does appear to be a gerund form of the verb "to threshold".

---

*What do the dictionaries say?*

Very few dictionaries seem to include "thresholding". I did find entries in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thresholding), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thresholding_(image_processing)), and [The Free Dictionary](https://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/thresholding), all of which are consistent with the idea that that word is a gerund. (Wiktionary calls it a noun, but even if it were one, I'd imagine that it was first a gerund.)

---

*If "thresholding" is a gerund, then is "to threshold" a verb?*

I couldn't find any dictionary entries for "threshold" as a verb. Perhaps that isn't surprising, since it seems to be in quite limited use, apparently only in the context of digital image processing.

Nevertheless, it's not unusual at all for a noun such as "threshold" to be used as a verb. ("Google" is a well-known example of a noun that has been verbed—as is "verb" itself!)

Furthermore, there are examples of the verb "threshold":

> Color images can also be thresholded.<sup>1</sup>

> Once you’ve decided to threshold, data visualization techniques like the ones in this post will let you understand the tradeoffs you face for each possible threshold choice.<sup>2</sup> (Noted by Stuart F in a comment elsewhere on this page.)

---

<sup>1</sup> "[Thresholding (image processing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thresholding_(image_processing))," Wikipedia

<sup>2</sup> "[Visualizing Machine Learning Thresholds to Make Better Business Decisions](https://blog.insightdatascience.com/visualizing-machine-learning-thresholds-to-make-better-business-decisions-4ab07f823415)," 9 October 2015

Comment: Thanks a lot, MarcInManhattan! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

*Thresholding* is a noun formed from a verb formed from a noun.

> **threshold**, *v.*
>  <sub>Etymology: < THRESHOLD *n.*</sub>
>
> *transitive.* To convert (a set of data, an image, etc.) to a binary form by reference to a threshold value; esp. to reproduce (an image)
> in two tones only, each part being dark or light according to whether
> the original is darker or lighter than a particular selected shade.
>
> ---
>
> DERIVATIVES
>
> **thresholding** *n.*
>
> <sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login
> required)</sub>